# reportlab textField wrong text color

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, reportlab

Something seems to be malfunctioning with my acroform.textfield. The text color in the textField always shows up blue. I'm trying to get the text color to be black, or (0,0,0). Even not setting it, the color should default to (.1,.1,.1). The trace itself when the textField is intiliased shows this:

```
"GET /pdf/ HTTP/1.1" 200 29132
> */lib/python3.6/site-packages/reportlab/pdfbase/acroform.py(819)_textfield()
-> ap = self.txAP(
(Pdb) fC
Color(1,1,1,1)
(Pdb) tC
Color(.1,.1,.1,1)
(Pdb) width
20
(Pdb) x
211.5
(Pdb) y
472.5
(Pdb) height
15
```

What actually prints (location coordintates printed for confirmation):

[image: text color shows up blue]

Any ideas?